# Is there a method to list all objects such as VIEWs that use a SYNONYM?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Like it says on the tin.
How can I determine which SQL objects are using a given SYNONYM? I suppose one way would be to search all contents of a PROC or VIEW and run a `LIKE '%SYN_NAME%'` but that seems very kludgy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * from sys.sql_expression_dependencies
where referenced_id = object_id('<syn schema>.<syn name>')
```

This view gives access to the tree of dependencies. So if want the objects which reference the objects this returns, you will need to recurse or similar.

You can restrict to views by a join to sys.objects or with objectproperty()

Comment: This is better. I voted to delete my post. I editted this one to join referencing_id back to sysobjects to get the referencing objects.

Comment: I think this might do it. Will do some testing on this over the next week or so. First time for us to use SYNONYMs.